# Need explanation on: Private Access modifier in java

Tags: java, oop, access-modifiers

I have two classes in Java: `Fist` class is extending `Person` class. I have a variable `eyecolor` in `Person` which is private and I have a public setter and getter for it.

Now if I extend it in Fist class then I can set the variable and I can also get it.

My question is if `eyecolor` is a private member of a class `Person`, why am I not getting an error of using a private member? Why is this code working? Is the `eyecolor` data member getting inherited?

Person Class

```
package lets_start;

public class Person {
    private String eyecolor;

    public String getEyecolor() {
        return eyecolor;
    }

    public void setEyecolor(String eyecolor) {
        this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
    }
}
```

Fist class

```
package lets_start;

public class Fist extends Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fist f = new Fist();
        f.setEyecolor("Brown");
        System.out.println(f.getEyecolor());
    }
}
```

Output:

> Brown

Comment: Through the public getter `getEyecolor`.

Comment: I'm not sure, what is your question.

Comment: `Fist` inherits the public getter and setter methods. _The private field is accessed in `Person` class only_. If you make a method in class `Fist` wherein you try to acces field `eyecolor` directly, then it will not compile.

Comment: please now review the question

Comment: "why I am not getting an error of using a private member?" because you're not accessing it directly, you're using the public getter. "Is the eyecolor data member get's inherited?" No it doesn't, it inherits the public getter/setter

Comment: Since `Fist` "is-a" `Person` there will be a private field `eyecolor`. But `Fist` won't be able to access it _directly_, because it is a private member of the ancestor. You seem to expect that the field will not exist at all ...

Comment: @RaounaqSharma `private` doesn't mean that the variable can only ever be used internally, it means it can only be accessed directly from inside the class. In main, `f.eyecolor` would be an error, but using a getter is fine; that's the point of the getter.

Comment: Where does the value gets stored when I do:

f.setEyecolor("Brown");

Comment: @RaounaqSharma Look at the definition of `setEyecolor`. It stores it in the private `eyecolor`. The setter is public, but it's modifying a private field. That's allowed. `setEyecolor` is defined inside the class, so it's allowed to modify private fields, even if the caller of `setEyecolor` isn't allowed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate  you said "It stores it in the private eyecolor", can you tell who's private "eyecolor", is it of Person or Fist. Most probably it is of Person, then the same thing I want to ask. Why is a public method changing a private data member of a class?

Comment: @RaounaqSharma Fist *is a* Person. The Fist class inherits the field from Person. And the "why" depends on who wrote it. 99% of the time, having a getter and setter that just change a private field is useless; it entirely defeats the purpose of having the field as private in the first place. In this example, you might as well get rid of the getter and setters, and just make the field public. This example code shows how to do it, but it's too simple to use it as an example of best practice.

Comment: And just to say it again: public methods are allowed to change private fields of the same class. Private fields are private because they're fragile, or contain data that you don't want the user to see/modify in case they begin relying on it, and you change how the class works later. The end users *use* the public methods, and the public methods often modify private fields. The get a better idea of why it's like this, read up on "encapsulation" and "data hiding".

Answer (score 1):

To access/edit it from child classes, either make the field `protected`/`package-private` or use the getter/setter you defined in `Person`.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

---

> why I be able to access it from its child classam not getting an error of using a private member? Why is this code working? Is the eyecolor data member get's inherited?

Because you access it through the `public` getter/setter which are inherited from `Person`. To make it clearer, `eyecolor` field is not inherited, getter/setter are.

Please feel free to edit your question or comment if it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't accessing the private member, you are accessing a public method.

Accessing the private member looks like this and will create a compile time  error:

```
package lets_start;

public class Fist extends Person {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fist f = new Fist();
        f.eyecolor = "Brown";
        System.out.println(f.eyecolor);
    }
}
```

Comment: So where the value gets stored when I do:

f.setEyecolor("Brown");